# Set UITextField text with a UIPickerView text programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit, uipickerview

I want to programmatically set the value of a UITextField with the content of a specific row of a UIPickerView (which is already its input).

This has to be done without opening the UIPickeView since I want to set a default value once the PickerView's data source is populated at runtime.

The solution I came with is this:

```
pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
textField.text = pvDataSource[ pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) ]
```

I want to know if there is a more elegant solution for it, like pretending the PickerView did show up and the user chose one of its options.

Comment: I think this is reasonably elegant, tbh I've always felt UIPickerView was a bit messy to deal with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked some old source that I'd written where I have the same type of interaction.

I have `UIPickerView` populated with some web resources, however it will default to a specific selection without any user interaction.

I have done exactly as you have done above. Grab the 0'th component and resolve that back to my UI.

I think that's as elegant as it gets with UIPickerViews.

Trying to wrap them in a further abstraction just isn't worth your time imo.